# why it is not correct (numpy.testing.assert_equal in python3)

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know why not correct; can anyone help, please?

```
def issc(x):
    avg = []
    for i in range(len(x)) :
        score = x[i]
        score = score.split(",")
        avg.append((int(score[0]) + int(score[1]) + int(score[2])) //3)
    win = max(avg)
    pos = avg.index(win) + 1
    return "(" + str(pos) + ", " + str(win) + ")"

import numpy as np
sc=0
try:
    np.testing.assert_equal(issc(['50,45,60', '80,75,85', '50,65,60', '85,80,79', '60,75,62']), (4, 81))
    print('correct')
    print(sc)
except Exception as e:
    print('not correct')
    print(e)
```

output: not correct

Items are not equal:

```
ACTUAL: '(4, 81)'  
DESIRED: (4, 81)
```

I don't know why not correct; anyone can help, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def issc(x):
    avg = []
    for i in range(len(x)) :
        score = x[i]
        score = score.split(",")
        avg.append((int(score[0]) + int(score[1]) + int(score[2])) //3)
    win = max(avg)
    pos = avg.index(win) + 1
    return pos, win
```